# Powershell script to activate MS Office

Tags: windows, powershell, ms-office

Today I tried to make a script to activate MS Office 2013.
Refering : https://www.apeswithcomputers.com/article/use-cscript-to-activate-office-2010-2013-2016

The script is not throwing any error, but the application license is not activating. Here is what I tried

```
$Key = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
$Executable = $env:windir + "\System32\cscript.exe"
$Proc1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs" + "/inpkey:" + $Key  
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $Proc1 -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized -Passthru
$Proc2 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs" + "/act"
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $Proc2 -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized -Passthru
```

What I am missing? Any help?

Try 1:

````
$Key = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
$Executable = $env:windir + "\System32\cscript.exe"
$Proc1 = "```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs```"" + " /inpkey:" + $Key
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $Proc1 -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized -Passthru
$Proc2 = "```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs```"" + " /act"
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $Proc2 -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized -Passthru
````

Try 2:

```
$Key = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
$Executable = $env:windir + "\System32\cscript.exe"
$VbsScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs"
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/inpkey:$Key" -Wait -Passthru
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/act" -Wait -Passthru
```

Try 3:

```
$Key = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
$Executable = $env:windir + "\SysWOW64\cscript.exe"
$VbsScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs" 
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/inpkey:$Key" -Wait -Passthru
Start-Process -FilePath $Executable -ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/act" -Wait -Passthru
```

Comment: To separate the switches and arguments, should it not read `" /inpkey:"`, and `" /act"`? instead of `"/inpkey:"`, and `"/act"`.

Comment: Hey Compo...Thanks for the reply....I made the change, but still the script is not working :(

Comment: Well I'd assume that you'd also need to cater for the spaces in your filepath(s), i.e. `$Proc1 = "```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\ospp.vbs```"" + " /inpkey:" + $Key` and `$Proc2 = "```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\ospp.vbs```"" + " /act"`.

Comment: No improvement Compo :(

Comment: You need to use `$VbsScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs"`, not `Office14` if you need this for Office 2013. Then, I'd suggest you should use the ArgumentList as array: `-ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/inpkey:$Key"` and for the second call `-ArgumentList $VbsScript, "/act`

Comment: Hey Theo...My mistake...I was using Office15 correctly in the script...But mentioned wrongly here...And I made the changes you stated...Still its not working :(

Comment: @jimmy20, instead of us having to guess what you may, or may not, have tried, how about you use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63314970/edit) button, and update your question with each of your failed attempts, so that we can be cartain that you're doing everything properly, instead of just telling us that you tried something and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you read the important message [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/tools-to-manage-volume-activation-of-office)? _"Before you run the ospp.vbs, ensure that:

**[1]** If you want to run the script on a remote computer, the Windows firewall allows Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) traffic on the remote computer.
**[2]** The user account you will use is a member of the Administrators group on the computer on which you run the script.
**[3]** You run ospp.vbs script from an elevated command prompt.
"_

Comment: Hi Theo...1) I am now testing in the local computer and the firewall is turned off. 2)Am running in administrator account. 3)Am using elevated terminal.

Comment: For 32-bit versions of MS Office -- located in C:\Program Files (x86) folder -- you may need to use 32-bit version of cscript.exe in SysWOW64 folder.  Try `$Executable = $env:windir + "\SysWOW64\cscript.exe"`.  Worth a mention.

Comment: Please, if you want to respond to someone in a comment, 'ping' that someone by typing the at-sign `@` followed by that someone's name. If you don't, nobody gets notified..

Comment: @leeharvey1 : No improvement :)